# Глобальная задержка Python

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо реализовать глобальную задержку в Python, т.е вместе использования `time.sleep()` после каждой строки, сделать задержку сразу для всего скрипта.
Как это можно сделать?

Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум, запустить под Python debugger.

Comment: Конкретнее, это как? Я просто не в курсе, новичок.

Comment: Я, вот, честно не понимаю, сюда попадают пользователи, у которых запретили гугл, отобрали интернет, ...? Делайте своё домашнее задание, прежде чем сюда приходить.

Comment: А вы не думали, то что если я задал вопрос тут, то я уже пробовал гуглить?  Я не понимаю, в чём проблема дать конкретный ответ, на конкретный вопрос. Либо тогда не пишите вообще. Это Stack Overflow как никак, и тут как раз таки задают вопросы.

Comment: У вас выше не вопрос, а задание. Почитайте правила SO как задавать и какие вопросы здесь приветствуются, а какие нет. Всего хорошего.

Comment: Правда, что вы хотите (условно) выполнять инструкцию - ждать секунду - выполнять инструкцию? Хм. а в каком контексте могло такое понадобиться?

Comment: Да. В контексте создания бота на Selenium,решения от самого Selenium в этом плане не подходят, и необходимо сделать именно такую задержку.

Comment: Только если в виртуальную машину дописать `sleep` и пересобрать Python с этим идиотским хаком. Только вряд ли это именно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Вообще посмотрите в сторону `sys.settrace`, там есть возможность выполнять код построчно. Еще можете посмотреть на то, как реализован pdb, который сделан поверх той же `sys.settrace`.